# Ionic show div only if toggle is checked

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have the following code set up

```
<ion-col>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label> Set safe zone for device</ion-label>
            <ion-toggle name ='safeZone' ></ion-toggle>
        </ion-item>
        <app-location-picker *ngIf= safeZone.checked>

        </app-location-picker>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-col>
```

and i only wish to display the app-location-picker if the ion-toggle i names safe-zone is checked i tried doing this but the system does not accept safezone after the ngif. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually didn't try the name property before, but for sure, you can try the ngModel property with it/instead.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Set safe zone for device</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="safeZone"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
<app-location-picker *ngIf="safeZone"></app-location-picker>
```